# How to increase SMTP limit?

Tags: java, php, android, smtp

I'm using an `SMTP` for sending an email from the application but as I have searched it only allowed to send 500 emails per day so is there any way through which I can send more than 10K SMTP email per day ? Else any other source through which we can send number of emails in `android` application

Comment: Are sure this is a limitation in your Android app? Sounds more like the limit comes from your SMTP server.

Comment: Since SMTP isn't built into Android, this limitation is from somewhere else.  Since we know nothing about your network setup, we can't help you.  But if you're sending this volume of email, you ought to use a service that deals with mass emails.  It will save you a lot of headaches down the line.

Comment: Yes @Kerbholz..is Correct There is No Limit in application it may on your SMTP Server Side You need you Upgrade your Plan.. Its not Related you Default App

Comment: But I have searched on google it says You can send only 500 emails per day through SMTP

Answer (score 0):

> I have searched on google it says You can send only 500 emails per day through SMTP

That is using the **free** Google Gmail service.

According to [this page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en), the limit on a Google G Suite account is 2,000 per user per day per user (or 500 for a trial account).  The G Suite documentation also [mentions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491#sendinglimitsforrelay) that the limits are higher if you are using the the SMTP relay service.

But be aware that you need to **pay** to use these services.